# Laravel search function crashes after page refresh

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, search, laravel-5.5

I have followinmg simple search function

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->term.'%')->paginate(10);
    return view('posts.search', compact('posts'));
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts', 'as' => 'posts.'], function () {
    Route::post('/search', ['as' => 'posts', 'uses' => 'SearchController@posts']);
});
```

And my view:

```
            <form action="{{ route('searches.posts') }}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input class="input blue-text text-lighten-3" type="text" name="term">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I call this function after I submit and get a new view with all the items related to the search. So far it works but if I now refresh the page I get following error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Comment: Please show the route and link you use.

Comment: Where do you get the `$term` variable from anyway?!

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form method is `post`, so on your initial request the HTTP method is POST. When you refresh the page the browser makes a GET request rather than a POST request.

Make sure your route is registered for GET and POST requests:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/search', ['as' => 'posts', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#basic-routing

You may also want to consider just switching your form method to `get`. This will cause the search parameters to appear in the URL and will enable users to link to search results.

Comment: This worked I think, could you add an explanation please

Comment: @Hensen Added! Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the wrong controller method. So, change this:

```
'uses' => 'SearchController@snippets'
```

To:

```
'uses' => 'SearchController@search'
```

Comment: my bad this is not the issue I copied the wrong part first

Comment: @Hensen well, you've updated with `@posts` method which is not `@search` too